# My sapient race has the ability to fly. How would this affect their basic architecture?

Tags: fantasy-races, flight, architecture

I’m writing a fairy-like humanoid race that have the ability of flight through biological/magical means. They are in their equivalent of an early medieval era and are the sole sapient species in their habitat.

Flying for them would use just a little more energy for them than jogging. On average they don't fly for long distances for travel but fly frequently in bursts to get around in everyday life. They feel a biological urge towards flight and it has cultural importance in sports/hunting/dance. Children of the species cannot fly and the ability develops over 2-4 years during puberty. Elderly members gradually lose their ability to fly.

Carrying something heavy during flight would be difficult if not impossible so building structures in high places would be hard without assistive construction equipment.

I am new to world building and don't know a lot about architecture outside of medieval castles and large structures. What would I need to consider when designing a basic residential structure build by this race?

Comment: I read the other query as one of big picture biocultural phenomena. And really, quite specific to Tomskeleton's particular winged people. My own winged people, Denê, don't share all of those traits, so their biocultural architecture is quite different. That said, you might get this reopened if you focus not on broad trends but rather on smaller details. L. Dutch gives you a great direction to head when modifying this query. Perhaps ask about a specific kind of structure or specific architectural elements or particular methods of construction. **More questions about winged people is better!!**

Answer (score 2):

> They feel a biological urge towards flight and it has cultural importance in sports/hunting/dance. Children of the species cannot fly and the ability develops over 2-4 years during puberty. Elderly members gradually lose their ability to fly.

It sounds like fly-dedicated buildings will be mostly devised for collective events like dance parties or sport exhibitions, nothing much different than modern discos or stadiums. However, being medieval times, they would probably be dance halls and large squares in the open (out of my mind, large structures equivalent to a stadium in medieval times were at most remains of the Roman time). The main difference I see is that those who can fly will not need to use stairs to move between different levels.

Probably the dance halls will have sort of privé floors, reachable only by flying and with the possibility of being sheltered from the outside with drapes.